# image Scaling of picture box

Tags: c#, image, image-scaling

i got a problem with image scaling in C#.

I have a picture Box with given Size : e.g. width = 800px height = 600px

I am loading different images into that picture box, small ones ( 400x400) and big ones (800+ x 600+)

My images are getting resized if they do not fit into box. But they are *always* resized to MAX width and height of PictureBox. So the aspect ratio is *destroyed*.

Can anybody help to identify / fix the problem?

**Classes:**

[Form1.cs](http://pastie.org/private/nlpczwuokemq4jwedulw)

[ImageHandling.cs](http://pastie.org/private/0fjxxktybiafuwu2glg0a) (commented out)

[ImageUtilities.cs](http://pastie.org/private/7h40w2eg5wvja8uohhyflq)

**Examples:**

Problem 1:
My Version
[image]

vs 
Original Source [image]

Problem 2:
My Version
[image]

vs 
Original Source
[image]

**How i want it:**

Solution
[image]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
this.PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
```

Set that property to your PictureBox and the size of the image will increased or decreased to fit the PictureBox maintaining the size ratio.

For more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode.aspx

Comment: It works now Thanks! I removed my resizing method and it worked. BUT my pictures are not in original size if they are smaller than picturebox. Any idea?

Comment: so, what you need is to resize the image only if it's bigger than the picturebox? and keep the size if it's smaller?

Comment: When the picture i want to load is smaller than my picture box, it is "zoomed" like the SizeMode says, but i dont want to zoom it. i want to display it in original size by keeping the aspect ratio.

Comment: then you'll probably have to do something like: `if(image.Width < pictureBox1.Width && image.Height < pictureBox1.Height){pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal;}else{pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;}`

Answer (score 0):

I handled this by resetting the SizeMode on the PictureBox's resize method.

This is, essentially, the same answer as above, but it's formatted much better.

```
private void ScaleImage()
{
  if (pbInfo.Image == null)
    return;

  if (pbInfo.Image.Width > pbInfo.Width || pbInfo.Image.Height > pbInfo.Height)
    pbInfo.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
  else
    pbInfo.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal;
}
```