# Get pixel perfect zooming

Tags: c#, graphics, zooming

I'm working on a pixel art editor and I stuck in an issue with zooming. I created a simple zooming function which is working properly except one thing... I can't get a pixel perfect result after zooming. I think it is self-explaining and don't need any further explanation what I'm thinking. I tried the different versions of InterpolatinMode but the picture still "smooth".

```
private Image ZoomPicture(Image img, Size size)
    {
        Bitmap temp_btm = new Bitmap(img, Convert.ToInt32(img.Width * size.Width), Convert.ToInt32(img.Height * size.Height));
        Graphics gpu = Graphics.FromImage(temp_btm);
        gpu.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;

        return temp_btm;
    }
```

Check the pictures:

[image]

[image]

Comment: "*I think it is self-explaining and don't need any further explanation*" never assume this. However `NearestNeighbor` is the lowest-quality mode and `HighQualityBicubic` is the highest-quality mode (in general and without getting bogged down into the algorithms and what they do), you also might want to consider setting `SmoothingMode.HighQuality` and `PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality`

Comment: Quality is in the eyes of the beholder. You want `NearestNeighbor`  for its 'lower' quality See here [image getting blurred when enlarging picture box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554126/image-getting-blurred-when-enlarging-picture-box/49556218?r=SearchResults&s=1|43.1814#49556218) - Also you are leaking the Graphics object!

Comment: Your entire scaled up image is created on the first line.  The other two lines don't do anything  -- it doesn't do any good to set the interpolation mode *after* the scaling is done.  Create a blank bitmap, graphics, set the interpolation mode, and then DrawImage the old image onto it

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answers! I could fix the issue by TaW's link... 

@TaW Can you explain how did you mean this "leaking the Graphics object" thing?

Comment: Most GDI objects are `IDisposable` i.e.need to be disposed of when no longer needed. Best by using a `using` clause: `Using (Graphics g = Graphics.fromImage(..)) {do stuff..}; return ..` as in the link. If you don't do that you may run out of GDI handles..