# How to parse a BDF bitmap font into arrays

Tags: c#, .net-core, fonts, bitmap, .net-5

I have this bitmap font (BDF) (https://github.com/lucy/tewi-font) and I need to parse it into arrays of pixels per character, or at least a way to draw a char into a Bitmap image without antialiasing.

Non platform specific classes if possible.

Comment: For the latter: Note sure about Core but for the winforms way see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49554126/image-getting-blurred-when-enlarging-picture-box/49556218#49556218)

Comment: @TaW I'm looking for functions specific to the BDF format, which is basically a text file

Comment: Honestly doesn't seem hard at all to make your own parser for it. Opening one of these files, the actual data can be decoded just by converting it to binary.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and wrote a small parser: [BdfFontParser](https://github.com/marcogruhl/BdfFontParser) (Nuget: [BdfFontParser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BdfFontParser)). The library parses the bdf file into a BdfFont object with all the properties.

**Usage:**

With the helper class `GetMapOfString` you will get your needed two-dimensional array for one character or a whole string:

```
using BdfFontParser;
using System.Text;

var font = new BdfFont("fonts/7x13B.bdf");

var map = bdfFont.GetMapOfString("Hello World");
var width = map.GetLength(0);
var height = map.GetLength(1);

var sb = new StringBuilder();

// draw line by line
for (int line = 0; line < height; line++)
{
    // iterate through every bit
    for (int bit = 0; bit < width; bit++)
    {
        sb.Append(map[bit,line] ? '#' : ' ');
    }    
        
    sb.AppendLine();
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

To visualize the a bdf font character and what the parser does the following hexdraw image from [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Unifont) is helpful:

```
00 00000000 --------
00 00000000 --------
00 00000000 --------
00 00000000 --------
18 00011000 ---██---
24 00100100 --█--█--
24 00100100 --█--█--
42 01000010 -█----█-
42 01000010 -█----█-
7E 01111110 -██████-
42 01000010 -█----█-
42 01000010 -█----█-
42 01000010 -█----█-
42 01000010 -█----█-
00 00000000 --------
00 00000000 --------
```